# code line is killing my program

Tags: c++, oop, list

i made this linked list class in c++ and it works fine except after i run it the program goes unresponsive. i have located the line that's causing the problem but i have no idea why. Even when i type it differently it still does the same thing.

Here's my list class:

```
#include <string>

 template<class T>
 class List : public Object{
private: 
    Node<T>* first;
    Node<T>* last;
    int length;
public:
    List() : Object(new std::string("List")) {
        first = NULL;
        last = NULL;
        length = 0;
    }
    ~List() {
        delete first;
        delete last;
    }

    void Add(T value) {
        if(first==NULL)
            first = new Node<T>(NULL, value);
        else if(last==NULL)
            ---->last = new Node<T>(first, value);<-----
        else
            last = new Node<T>(last, value);
        length++;
    }

    T Remove(T value) {
        Node<T>* temp = first;
        while(temp!=NULL) {
            if(temp->GetValue()==value) {
                temp->GetPrev()->SetNext(temp->GetNext());
                temp->GetNext()->SetPrev(temp->GetPrev());
                delete temp;
                length--;
                return value;
            }
            temp = temp->GetNext();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    T Get(int index) {
        Node<T>* temp = first;
        int i = 0;
        while(temp!=NULL) {
            if(i==index)
                return temp->GetValue();
            i++;
            temp = temp->GetNext();
        }
        return 0;
    }
 };
```

when i remove the marked line above the program go unresponsive. This is my Node constructor:

```
#include <string>

template<class T>
class Node : public Object{
private:
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    T value;
public:
    Node(Node* prev, T value) : Object(new std::string("Node")){
        if(prev!=NULL) {
            prev->next = this;
            this->prev = next;
        } 
        next = NULL;
        this->value = value;
    }
    ~Node() {
        delete next;
    }

    T GetValue() {
        return value;
    }

    Node* GetNext() {
        return next;
    }

    Node* GetPrev() {
        return next;
    }
};
```

my object class:

```
#include <string>

class Object {
private:
    std::string* type;
public:
    Object() {
        type = new std::string("Object");
    }
    Object(std::string* type) {
        this->type = type;
    }
    ~Object() {
        delete type;
    }

    std::string* GetType() {
        return type;
    }
};
```

my Test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Object.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {

List<int> l;
l.Add(5);
l.Add(93);
l.Add(17);
l.Add(7789);
l.Add(60);

cout << "node 4 is:" << l.Get(3) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

error image http://i50.tinypic.com/2mw5phi.png
thanks for reading and please help as soon as you can, comment if you need me to supply more info.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No the output is fine. the list works it just makes my program not respond and windows give that not responding error

Comment: Your constructor is referencing `prev`.  But `prev` is not shown in scope in the code you've posted.  Please post *enough* code to show all relevant variables and operations.

Comment: Could it be going into an infinite loop/recursion? (it doesn't appear to be doing so in this code, but could easily be doing so based on other code contingent on that line). If you add something like `cout << "add\n"` to the top of the `Add` function, does it keep getting infinitely printed?

Comment: Have you tried sampling the program while it's unresponsive?

Comment: To me it seems that the case `first != NULL && last==NULL`, which triggers your marked line, should never occur - it would mean the list is inconsistent. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: What does your `Object` constructor do?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C++.pdf

Comment: That picture means your program triggered an exception. Most likely trying to access a `NULL`/invalid pointer. What IDE are you using? Try to run it with a debugger, it will tell you were exactly the illegal access is happening.

Comment: my IDE is sublime-text 2, windows explorer, mingw activated through a batch file that lets me select the program i wanna run

Comment: Well, that doesn't technically qualify as an IDE for C++ - you need something which has an integrated debugger etc.

Comment: i've used DevC++ in the past but it gave me more errors and technical problems than any program i have ever used. and i dont want ms- visual c++ because they just do everything differently. any suggestions?

Comment: lethal-guitar, the if(last==NULL) will not be touched if first is NULL because i put it in an else if so only if first==NULL is false will last==NULL be checked

Comment: @user1494136 It will not be touched - and that exactly is the problem. Because `last` will still be NULL after you add the first element. Which is inconsistent, it should be set to `first` in the first if block.

Comment: As for IDE choice: There are many to pick from, but coding C++ without a proper debugger is like trying to dig a large hole using a tea spoon. Believe me. Get used to one now.

Comment: k thanks for the advise i tried this code but still the same error, it's like c++ doesn't want me to put first in last's constructor call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** There are many problems with your program, but what might be causing your crash: Your `Add`-function does not work correctly. It should be something like this:

```
if(first==NULL) {
    first = new Node<T>(NULL, value);
    last = first;
} else {
    last = new Node<T>(last, value);
}
length++;
```

Otherwise, it will not correctly insert the second element. Why? With your original code, after the first add, your `last` is still NULL because of the `else`. So on the second add, you set last to `new Node<T>(NULL, value)`. Therefore, it will not assign the first element's `next` pointer. And your list will be inconsistent.

Apart from that, there are double-frees, unnecessary heap-allocation of the `string` field in your Object class, ownership issues etc. To give you just one more example: Your `List` destructor will cause a heap corruption due to a double free. Calling `delete first` will delete all nodes due to the `delete next` in `Node`'s destructor, as long as the list is consistent. Then you call `delete last`, but that object was already freed. This will corrupt your program's memory management and can also cause a crash at program exit.

Comment: after adding two i want the second is the last and the first is first thats why i wrote `last = new Node<T>(first, value);` and then i wanna keep my last as the last node so `last = new Node<T>(last, value);` did it like this because i only wanted to set first as prev on the second add() call. another way to do this is: `if(first==NULL) { first = new Node<T>(NULL, value); last = first; }else last = new Node(last, value);`

Comment: Yeah sure, but then you're still missing `last = first` in the first if in `Add()` - otherwise, `last` will just be left as NULL for a list with one element.

Comment: thats not true, i wrote `if(last==NULL) last = new Node(first, value);` any way i tried the other code too but still same error. whats wierd is that it prints `l.Get(3);` fine just it dies after that. i've treid a lot of different ways to make this add() method execute the same but none seem to work. it's like when ever i put first in the last-node's constructor it dies.

Comment: Maybe I found your problem: Your Node constructor only sets `prev` if `next != NULL`, even though it should set it to NULL in that case.

Comment: Yes, but that line is in the else branch. It will not be executed when adding the first element. At least not in your current code.

Comment: I've edited my answer to point out what I believe is a serious problem in your code.

Comment: Holy crap! thank you sooooo much lethal-guitar, i deleted the seconde delete (`delete last;`) and it just magically works. thanks a bunch you too David

Comment: You're welcome. Well, that's not "magic" - you had a double free, which corrupted your heap and caused your program to crash after it terminated.

Answer (score 2):

Does this function seem correct to you??

It says `GetPrev`, but its actually getting `next`.

```
Node* GetPrev() {
    return next;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i just fixed it and run the program but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I comment out this line in the `Node` constructor the code compiles:

```
if (next != NULL) {
    // next->next = this;
    prev = next;
}
```

**Edit 1:**

I also realized that you were doing this in your `Node` class:

```
private:
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    T value;
```

Since these objects are declared in the `Node` class, they are at this time incomplete types. I managed to replicate that problem down to a simple one like [this](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0a15df80655355822f2293883b6b656f):

```
template <class T>
struct S {
    S* s = new S();
    ~S() { delete s; }
};

int main() {
    S<int> s; // Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./test > .stdout
}
```

This causes a crash because `S` is an incomplete type within itself.

I'm getting the same segementation fault as I got in your code. I'm pretty sure it's because the pointers in the `Node` class are built upon incomplete types; and accessing the data from them is looking into memory that isn't yours, hence the crash.

Comment: the unresponding error doesn't occur but my code doesn't work. see if i don't set my next parameter's (which really should be called prev) next to this then all the nexts of all the nodes will stay NULL the fore the list will only be linked through prev which cause it to actually loose link.

Comment: so i should change `Node* next` to `Node<T>* next` ? thanks for you input by the way

Comment: @user1494136 That wouldn't work either. `Node` would still be an incomplete type..I'm still looking for a solution

Comment: maybe the solution could be reached with the adress of operator (&) maybe the parameter in the Node() constructor Should be Node& next, instead of Node* next

Comment: @user1494136 Yes, in fact you shouldn't be using pointers for this stuff at all (in C++)! References are a better alternative in this case. I'll try to redo your code using this.

Comment: @user1494136 [Try this code](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e68bef4fa9235c747f1797d75a73e740)

Comment: thanks! but it appears all that was needed to do was erase the line `delete last;` in the list deconstructor. thanks a bunch for your help though